# Are user1234-like display names automatically generated?

Tags: discussion, new-users

On the Stack Exchange network, I've seen nicknames like user1234, that is the word user plus a number. Are they automatically generated when, say, someone registers via existing account on some other platform?

**EDIT** It is not about user IDs, but display names.

Comment: That was the default username format a long time ago, now you have to specify your own display name.

Comment: @user000001, Are you the First one? Are they all your child?

Comment: @DragandDrop the reason behind my username is in the last paragraph of Martijn's answer. :)

Answer (score 6):

For most such users, such a display name has been generated from the user id, just with `user` added in front.

Your account, for example, has user id *1259152* (just look at the URL of [your profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259152/olegst)), so if you didn't pick `olegst`, you'd be given `user1259152` instead.

These days, users must always provide a display name, and it is no longer generated for you, but that hasn't always been the case. Also, moderators can reset your display name (e.g. when an offensive name has been picked), at which point the display name will revert to be generated. So if you see a user account whose display name number matches their account number (on the oldest account in the network), they either never picked a custom name at a time when that was an option, or they had their name reset.

Some accounts have explicitly picked a display name using the same pattern, but with a number that they feel is significant, or funny, or otherwise has meaning.

Comment: Why [Brad Gilbert here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1337/brad-gilbert) didn't stick with the anonymous name I'll never know...

Comment: ... And what ever happened [to this guy?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/69)  Doesn't have any posts, according to the sede.  Maybe that particular account was ... skipped? ... on purpose?